# How to increase days after every 5 or some specific number using php while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

```
$x = 1;
$z = 1;
while($row = $qry->fetch())
{
    $var = 5; //random
    $total = 5; //Dynamic
    if($var>=$total)
    {
        $fx = $x+1;
        $day = "day ".$x; //day1
    }
    elseif($var>=$z)
    {
        $y = $x+1;
        $day = "$var>=$z---day "."$y";//Day Increment
        $z++;
        if($z>$var)
        {
            $z=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code output as

```
day 1
day 1
day 1
day 1
day 1
5>=1---day 2
5>=2---day 2
5>=3---day 2
5>=4---day 2
5>=5---day 2
5>=1---day 2
5>=2---day 2
5>=3---day 2
5>=4---day 2
5>=5---day 2
```

What i want is after every 5th count day should be increased to 1. How to do it. I think missing some logic here. Kindly help me out.

Result should be

```
day 1
day 1
day 1
day 1
day 1
5>=1---day 2 //Note
5>=2---day 2
5>=3---day 2
5>=4---day 2
5>=5---day 2
5>=1---day 3
5>=2---day 3
5>=3---day 3
5>=4---day 3
5>=5---day 3
```

Note: This day count should be incremented in loop

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's hard to say what is missing if you're asking that yourself already. How would you answer "What is modulo?". A division operation in integer arithmetic might also be of use solving the puzzle.

Comment: I didn't get what you want, please add an example of the output you want

Comment: #hakre I'm confused. Module is travel to different places based team members strength. Days should be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem you want to loop and each `$var` iteration increment a number by 1.

For that you can use the `%` (modulo) operator that is the remainder of the Euclidean division.

```
$var = 5; // number of iterations before increasing $day
$day = 1; // current day
$i = 0; // iterator
while( ... ){
   //...
   i++;
   if( i % $var ==  $var-1 ) $day++;
}
```

or as an equivalent you can also do

```
$var = 5; // number of iterations before increasing $day
$day = 0; // current day
$i = 0; // iterator
while( ... ){
   if( i % $var == 0 ) $day++;
   //...
   i++;
}
```